# Why is my screenscale null?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I am creating a scaling matrix for my 2d tower defense game with this code:

```
float screenscalex;
float screenscaley;
Matrix SpriteScale;
screenscalex = (float)_graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 1366f;
screenscaley = (float)_graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 768f;
SpriteScale = Matrix.CreateScale(screenscalex, screenscaley, 1);
```

However it says that where screenscalex is initialized that it is a null reference. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I tried using GraphicsAdapter to get the width of the screen but it didn't work. Also, I haven't set the viewport to anything. Finally, moving the code to Initialize() just makes the game crash

Comment: how is _graphics initialized?

Comment: _graphics is a GraphicsDeviceManager it is initialized like this: _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);

Comment: Relative to this code, where is the GraphicsDeviceManager initialised?

Comment: In the same place(just above): the game1 constructor

Comment: Try moving the code into the Initialize or LoadContent method.

Comment: All of it? Plus, put in your comment as a answer.

Comment: Nope that didn't work the game just crashes and goes to the star screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this below base.Initialize() which is where that is initialized at..

Comment: Yeah that's what i did

Comment: Thats just makes the game crash

Comment: Nvm the game crashes but not because of the screenscale